# How to use the Google API Explorer with startTime for google calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use this api explorer here

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it

All other p[arameters works but i am not able to use

`timeMin` and `timeMax`

It gives error but not specific anyone.

Can anyone give me example of anything to put in `timeMin` which works

If i use like this

[image]

Then it works but if i add the timeMax like this , then i get error[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a time, that's a date. You need an ISO format datetime, eg `"2013-08-10T00:00:00Z"` (the Z is the timezone, in this case UTC).

Comment: thanks for thaty. Now i dont get error. i used this in timeMIn `2013-08-10T00:00:00Z` and `2013-11-10T00:00:00Z` in `timeMax` but it still returns the events which were back in `2010`. i want to get events whose starttime is betwen today and 2 months from today